# PHP MYSQL. How to retrieve the same data from a table based on 2 different ID's in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a website for Airplane Tickets, i have 2 tables, AIRPORTS and AIRPLANES, the AIRPLANES table has 2 columns containing its airport destination id(ID_DESTINATION) and its airport origin id(ID_ORIGIN), what i want to do is to loop all of the AIRPLANES using `while` with the AIRPORT_NAME as its origin and destination from the AIRPORTS table, how can i do that?

this is the query i'm using :

```
SELECT a.ID_PLANE, a.PLANE_NAME, 
       a.ID_ORIGIN, a.ID_DESTINATION, 
       a.TAKEOFF, a.LANDING, a.PRICE,
       b.ID_AIRPORT, b.AIRPORT_NAME
FROM AIRPLANES AS a
LEFT JOIN AIRPORTS AS b
ON a.ID_ORIGIN = b.ID_AIRPORT
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code for you. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected results.  It appears you may just need two joins to airports with different aliases.  Once for groin, once for destination.  SQL operates best in terms of "SETS" operating one at a time in loops is sub optimal for database systems.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I'm sorry, but i'm not asking anyone to write codes for me, I'm just asking "How do i retrieve the same data in a specific table based on 2 different ids from another table" , should i use join? union? transaction? cz i've tried them all, and its still not working

Comment: @xQbert so i have to use more than 1 query ?

Comment: No.  Just an additional LEFT join to airports (example below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice I aliased O for origin D for destination
Assuming you just want the names of airports for each airplane (flight)

```
SELECT a.ID_PLANE
     , a.PLANE_NAME
     , a.ID_ORIGIN
     , a.ID_DESTINATION
     , a.TAKEOFF
     , a.LANDING
     , a.PRICE
     , o.ID_AIRPORT as Orig_ID
     , o.AIRPORT_NAME Orig_Name
     , d.ID_AIRPORT as Dest_ID
     , d.AIRPORT_NAME Dest_Name
FROM AIRPLANES AS a
LEFT JOIN AIRPORTS AS o
  ON a.ID_ORIGIN = b.ID_AIRPORT
LEFT JOIN AIRPORTS d
  ON a.ID_DESTINATION = b.ID_AIRPORT
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you just use a sql-join?
http://www.sql-join.com/